# Is there any way to encapsulate RTP/RTSP/RTCP into one TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, proxy, vlc

**Here is my setup :**

I have 2 blackbox communicating with each other using some sort of radio.
Both blackbox can send/receive at the same time.

I can send/receive data to each of these blackbox using a TCP client socket on a predefined port.

I'm able to send/receive files but it's not as sexy as videos for demonstration purpose.

```
FILE --> APP --> BLACKBOX_TX --RADIO--> BLACKBOX_RX --> APP --> FILE
```

**Here is what I want to do :**

I would like to send a video from one side to another while being able to see the video from the TX side as well as the RX side. Of course the magic happens at the RX side and I should be able to see the video without loss because that's what the blackbox does.

**Here is my question :**

I've used VLC a few years back to send a video using RTP and its two friends RTSP and RTCP. Any chance I could use the same thing by muxing all flow connection into one TCP connection (towards the TX side) and demuxing from one TCP connection (from the RX side) ?

```
VLC --> [PROXY] --> BLACKBOX_TX --RADIO--> BLACKBOX_RX --> [PROXY] --> VLC
```

I'm open to any other kind of solution not involving VLC. The blackbox + TCP is a must.

Thanks,

SOKS

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your setup. You can just "duplicate" the video on the TX side, watch one part, and send the other part to the RX side. But that is totally independent on how TX and RX communicate. If the problem is that you want a full LAN connection between TX and RX, and you only have a single TCP port accessible, you can tunnel (GRE, OpenVPN, whatever).

Comment: The "duplicate" solution is not OK. It's for a demonstration purpose, both computers running VLC instances will be next to to other, and while the TX side video is being played, 
I want to play the RX video, so that people can notice how much latency there is (I introduce errors at the radio level, but the blackboxes have a reliable transport protocol implementation, so that no loss is guaranteed but it impacts the latency.)

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with checking "Display locally" as explained [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/) on the TX VLC instance? This will run two VLC instances next to each other (one on TX, one on RX), the TX side will stream and display simultanously, and latency will be perfectly demonstrated on the RX side. Or do you want to a round trip, and run both VLC on the sending side? Sorry, I am still confused. :-(

Comment: Didn't understand what you wrote I guess ! 
It's OK if I have only one PC sending/receiving (it acts as both the VLC from the TX side and the VLC from the RX side).
I guess I could use HTTP instead of RTP to simplify things right ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to repeat what I understood about the setup and the hope it's correct; if not, please update the question. Here is a picture, IP addresses are made up:

```
Computer A      Blackbox B      Blackbox C      Computer D
Laptop etc.     Embedded        Embedded        Laptop
10.0.0.1/24 --- 10.0.0.2/24 ... 10.0.1.2/24 --- 10.0.1.1/24
                Port 123        Port 123
```

So A and B are connected by Ethernet (LAN), B and C by your radio, and C and D again by Ethernet. There is an application running on B and C which listens on port 123, and will forward everything from or to that port to the other side via radio. You want to run VLC on A and D and stream a video to demonstrate the latency involved.

In that case, I'd set up a tunnel with `socat` in the following way. On A,

```
socat TCP4:10.0.0.2:12 TUN:10.0.2.1/24,iff-up
```

and on B,

```
socat TCP4:10.0.1.2:12 TUN:10.0.2.2/24,iff-up
```

Check with `ip route` on both A and D that you have something like

```
10.0.2.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src ...
```

This sort of pretends that A and D are connected directly, just like over a LAN, like in this picture:

```
A                 D
10.0.2.1/24 ----  10.0.2.2/24
tun0              tun0
```

Test that this works by doing `ping 10.0.2.2` from A, and if the radio connection is bidrectional, with `ping 10.0.2.1` from D. If the connection is not bidirectional, you may potentially have trouble, I am not sure.

(I have tested this using a slightly different setup, but can't test an unidrectional connection. I have not tested VLC streaming as described below).

Now you can start a stream sending VLC instance on A and a stream receiving VLC instance on D. All protocols should work in theory (if the radio connection is bidirectional), try them all. If the radio connection is unidirectional, RTP and UDP *should* work. The *destination* of the stream is `10.0.2.2` (tunnel address of D) for the UDP and RTP method. If you send via HTTP, the receiver needs something like `vlc http://10.0.2.1:8080/go.mpg`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed, you understand correctly and made an accurate answer that will fill my need.
I will try your solution when I'll have some time (in a few days or so) but the logic is pretty clear. I'll keep you posted ! :)